# How to get DNN to create a sitemap links for custom modules?

Tags: dotnetnuke, sitemap

We have a DNN website with custom modules which uses Ajax to load Grid Items.

How can I get DNN to create a sitemap for these links as well? I am currently using an external program but would like DNN to generate these sitemaps automatically with all our links.

The site is: https://www.parrot.co.za

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically do this by creating a SiteMap provider for your module.

You can find a working example in my [DNNSimpleArticle module on GitHub](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/dnnsimplearticle)

```
 public class Sitemap : SitemapProvider
    {

        public override List<SitemapUrl> GetUrls(int portalId, PortalSettings ps, string version)
        {
            var listOfUrls = new List<SitemapUrl>();

            foreach (Article ai in ArticleController.GetAllArticles(portalId))
            {

                var pageUrl = new SitemapUrl
                              {
                                  Url =
                                      ArticleController.GetArticleLink(ai.TabID, ai.ArticleId),
                                  Priority = (float)0.5,
                                  LastModified = ai.LastModifiedOnDate,
                                  ChangeFrequency = SitemapChangeFrequency.Daily
                              };
                listOfUrls.Add(pageUrl);

            }
            return listOfUrls;
        }
    }
```

and then you need to register the sitemap with DNN in the .DNN file used during the module's installation

```
<component type="Config">
          <config>
            <configFile>web.config</configFile>
            <install>
              <configuration>
                <nodes>
                  <node path="/configuration/dotnetnuke/sitemap/providers" action="update" key="name" collision="overwrite">
                    <add name="DNNSimpleArticleSiteMapProvider" type="Christoc.Modules.dnnsimplearticle.Providers.Sitemap.Sitemap, DNNSimpleArticle" providerPath="~\DesktopModules\dnnsimplearticle\Providers\Sitemap\" />
                  </node>
                </nodes>
              </configuration>
            </install>
            <uninstall>
              <configuration>
                <nodes />
              </configuration>
            </uninstall>
          </config>
        </component>
```

Comment: How would I change the foreach loop? Currently, our Detailed Product View module loads a specific product depending on the SKU in the URL which is a query string. The TABID stays the same so we are using one module to dynamically load our product details on a template.

Comment: Make the way you build your URL customer. Example of what the FOR loop calls in getarticlelink https://github.com/ChrisHammond/dnnsimplearticle/blob/551174b20c6421a1faf562320b3c5f6f4f5e4e7b/Components/ArticleController.cs#L152